# Can python's 'super' give child classes its parent classes class variables

Tags: python, super

I am trying to make it to where I can have multiple child classes from, for example class `a`, and I want all of the variables declared in class `a`'s `__init__` method to be in all of the child classes, while also not needing to enter any `*args` into the `__init__` method.

My example parent class is:

```
class a:
    def __init__(self):
        self.t = 5
```

and my example child class is:

```
class c(a):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```

does class `c` have the variable `t` from class `a`?
Would it be equal to 5?

While messing around with this, I get the error `AttributeError: type object 'c' has no attribute 't'`, but shouldn't `super().__init__()` get the variable t from class `a` and make it to where class `c` has it too?

Comment: Have you instantiated the class? You should do something like `c_instance = c()` and then access `c_instance.t`

Comment: You need to instantiate the class in order for `__init__` to be invoked.  Just to this:  `instance = c()` then `print(instance.t)` and you'll get `5`.

Comment: "While messing around with this" We can only tell you what is wrong with code that you show to us exactly, not code that you vaguely recall.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're right, but the error occurs because you trying to access `t` on the class itself and not its instance. The following should work:

```
inst = c()
print(inst.t)  # 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1


class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.b = self.a
        print(self.b)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    B()
```

Code example like this. You'll get 1 in command line. So just use self.attr.